# Getting Address Autocomplete (Google Places Library of JavaScript API) Request Count in Code

Tags: google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-places-api

Google Places API Web Service provides 1,000 requests (raised to 150,000 if you provide billing info for proof of identity). Places Library utilizes the Places Web Service and counts against its limit.

Currently I am trying to add the address autocomplete to an existing address input in an angularjs application.

This seems to be working correctly where, when the Google Places API Web Service is enabled the field has an autocomplete dropdown and when it is disabled, it is just the ordinary input field.

**Issue:** When I hit the usage limit, instead of disabling the service, the dropdown continues to populate. However, when the user attempts to select an option an error is logged to the web console and an incomplete object is returned to my site (which does not look good for users).

Is there a way to either disable the service when the limit is hit (such that users see the standard input field) or to check the request count (or if the limit has been hit) prior to attaching the autocomplete to the input field?

I know a lot of the other API calls have a status returned which state when the limit is exceeded but this does not seem to be the case with address autocomplete because it is built on top of the Places Web Service.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it returns OVER_QUERY_LIMIT which indicates that you are over your quota.

[check google documentation here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete#place_autocomplete_status_codes)

Comment: Unfortunately that is the places address autocomplete in the Google Places API Web Service. I am trying to use the autocomplete in the Places Library in the Google Maps JavaScript API. [Places Web Service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) and [Places Library JS API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places)

Comment: are you using java script api or web service api ? as per your original post it looks like you are using web service api

Comment: Right, so I am using the JavaScript API which utilizes the Web Service API and has the same limits (and the requests are actually logged against the Web Service API which must be enabled to use the places library in the JavaScript API). Will update to be more clear.